# C++ Counting number of objects in a tree structure

Tags: c++, function, class, recursion

I am trying to perform the following.

1. I have two classes A and B, A is a superclass of B.
2. A can have children, but B  can't.
3. A1 has children B1 and A2 and A2 has children B2 and B3.
4. A1->descendants() should return the number of objects "under" A1, that is 4.

However, it keeps on returning 2. Can anyone help? Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A{
public:
    string name;
    vector<A*> children;
    int n=0;

   A(string aName){
        this->name=aName;
    }

    void addChild(A* aChild){
     children.push_back(aChild);
   }

   int descendants(){
       if(children.size()==0){
           n=0;
       }else{
           for(int i=0;i<children.size();i++){
               n=n+1;
               if(children[i]->children.size()!=0){
                   children[i]->descendants();
               }
           }
       }
       return n;
   }

 };


class B:public A{
public:
    string name;

   B(string aName) : A(aName) {
       this->name=aName;
   }
};






int main() {

A* A1=new A("A1");
A* A2=new A("A2");
B* B1=new B("B1");
B* B2=new B("B2");
B* B3=new B("B3");

A1->addChild(B1);
A1->addChild(A2);
A2->addChild(B2);
A2->addChild(B3);

cout<<A1->descendants()<<endl;

}
```

P.S. I have looked through similar questions, but I believe this one differs as I want to return an integer number and not update descendants every time a new child is added.
Thanks!

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve]. In particular, which objects are needed and is the derived class `B` necessary? Also, clearly state the expected and actual output of your program. Oh, and format your code consistently, it helps both you and other readers to understand the structure.

Comment: Can you explain what "`children[i]->descendants();`" is supposed to accomplish, and the exact, precise manner, in which that happens. Keep staring at this line in your code until you figure out your own bug. Remember the golden rule of computer programming: a computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. What exactly did you tell your computer to do, by this line of code?

Comment: `n` in `A1` is a different variable than in `A2` and the others.

Comment: `n` shouldn't be a member variable of the class, but a local variable of the function! As a local variable, you get two advantages: At first, you don't modify `this` any more (pretty meaningless anyway), so you can (and should!!!) declare the function `const`. Additionally, as only local variables get modified, you even can call the function concurrently from different threads (each call has its own copy of `n` then), which is not possible with the member variable.

Comment: Consider returning `unsigned int` or even better `size_t` (not for greater range, but because negative values are just plain meaningless).

Comment: You can simplify the code a bit (applies for accepted answer as well): Instead of `++num` inside loop, just initialise `num = children.size()`. Range-based for-loop would be much nicer, too: `for(auto const& child : children) { num += child.decendants(); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    string name;
    vector<A*> children;

    A(string aName){
        this->name=aName;
    }

    void addChild(A* aChild){
        children.push_back(aChild);
    }

    int descendants(){
        int numDescendants = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<children.size();i++){
            numDescendants++;
            numDescendants += children[i]->descendants();  // IMPORTANT: Add the number of grandchildren to the total, too
        }
        return numDescendants;
   }

 };


class B:public A{
public:
    string name;

    B(string aName) : A(aName) {
        this->name=aName;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* A1=new A("A1");
    A* A2=new A("A2");
    B* B1=new B("B1");
    B* B2=new B("B2");
    B* B3=new B("B3");
    B* B4=new B("B4");
    A1->addChild(B1);
    A1->addChild(A2);
    A2->addChild(B2);
    A2->addChild(B3);
    B3->addChild(B4);
    cout<<A1->descendants()<<endl;
}
```